# The pysimplgui app says I am reusing a layout, but I clearly change the layout, what is the problem?

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

```
layout_new = [[text_welc], [but_CrAcc], [text_AlrAcc], [but_login], [but_close]]

layout_login = [[text_user], [input_user], [text_pass], [input_pass], [but_close]]

layout_create = [[gui.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")], [gui.Button("Close")], [gui.Button("New Spreadsheet")]]

# Create the window
window = gui.Window("Fast Sheets", layout_new, size=(1000, 1000))

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # presses the OK button
    if event == "Close" or event == gui.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "New Spreadsheet":
        receipt1.Notebook()
    elif event == "Log in":
        window = gui.Window("Fast Sheets", layout_login, size=(1000, 1000))
```

Thats the code, and all the layouts are different, yet it says I am reusing them (PS The button and text variables have been defined earlier in code, just didnt want to paste everything as it would be too much)

I tried changing the window name etc but that did nothing

Comment: `but_close` is in 2 layouts.  The re-use is at the element level.  Can't have the same element in multiple layouts/windows.

Comment: What's the exact error message?  Posting a screenshot of the error window would be helpful. The error message was improved in the PSG on GitHub to make the reason for the error a little clearer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.